# Is the User's lat/lng inside the Company's lat/lng boundary

Tags: python, django

I have three pieces of data:

```
- user's current lat/lng
- company's current lat/lng
- bounding distance
```

I need to check if the user's `lat/lng` is inside a circle created by the `bounding distance` (example 100 metres), using the company's `lat/lng` as the centre. I hope that makes sense ...

Using these three values, all I really need is a True/False.
Are they or are they not in this space.

*Without using any DB additives, ala geodjango would be great.*

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Edit

I removed a previous version, using radians, and integrated successive edits in the final format of the answer

---

To use the following, `user` is a position on Earth that must be represented by a tuple/list/ndarray of length 2, the first element being the latitude, in degrees, the second the longitude, in degrees as well... the position of `company` must be represented in the same way, finally `radius` must be specified in metres. (there is also a `debug` optional variable, that enables printing a debugging help)

```
def is_close(user,company,radius, debug=0):
    "user=(lat, lon) in degrees, company=(lat, lon), radius in m"
    from math import cos, pi, sqrt
    EarthRadius   = 6.371E6 # metre, = 6371 km
    deg2rad = pi/180.0

    # localize the equirectangular projection to the latitude
    # (the 1st coordinate) of the company
    radius_x = EarthRadius*cos(company[0]*deg2rad)
    radius_y = EarthRadius

    dx, dy = ((user[1]-company[1])*deg2rad*radius_x,
              (user[0]-company[0])*deg2rad*radius_y)
    if debug:print dx, dy, sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)
    return True if (dx*dx+dy*dy) <= (radius*radius) else False
```

and eventually a version that uses a list of users, to bypass the function call overheads

```
def are_close(users, company, delta):
    from math import cos, pi
    # uses angles in degrees, uses Equirectangular projection
    rx = 6.371E6*pi/180.*cos(company[0]*pi/180)
    ry = 6.371E6*pi/180.
    close = []
    for user in users:
        dx = (user[1]-company[1])*rx
        dy = (user[0]-company[0])*ry
        close.append(True if dx*dx+dy*dy-r*r <= 0 else False)
    return close
```

#### Addendum

An example of usage from the interactive prompt

```
>>> def is_close(user,company,radius, debug=0):
...     from math import cos, pi, sqrt
...     EarthRadius   = 6.371E6 # metre, = 6371 km
...     deg2rad = pi/180.0
...     radius_x = EarthRadius*cos(company[0]*deg2rad)
...     radius_y = EarthRadius
...     dx, dy = ((user[1]-company[1])*deg2rad*radius_x,
...               (user[0]-company[0])*deg2rad*radius_y)
...     if debug:print dx, dy, sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)
...     return True if (dx*dx+dy*dy) <= (radius*radius) else False
... 
>>> user, company = (48.860384,2.338520), (48.859282,2.343369)
>>> is_close(user,company,500, 1)
-354.73500519 122.536809163 375.302802424
True
>>> is_close(user,company,500)
True
>>>
```

Comment: wow man, comprehensive answer, much appreciated. Just playing with this now, a few questions; the below is an example of two points, the user and company being around 500 metres apart and the outcome produces a False. Am I doing something wrong. Perhaps my 'radius' is being measured incorrectly?

`uc = (48.860384, 2.338520)  # Paris - Musee du Louvre ... 
cc = (48.859282, 2.343369)  # Paris - Rue du Pont Neuf ... 
r = 0.5  # Aprox 500m apart`